# How do get my add to cart buttons to only use the value from that individual item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, shopping-cart

I'm building a seed e-commerce site for my farmer friend to help build my portfolio and save hime some $$.  I'm a beginner so it's been quite the learning experience.

Right now I'm having trouble with the number input fields that are used to an item's quantity before adding to the cart.  I'm using the "id" tag, which I know is wrong, but I can't figure out what to use so that the value for one item doesn't affect the value of another item.

So my questions:

What do I use in my html to uniquely identify the value for each item/product?

How do I tweak my javascript to distinguish between each item's unique quantity?

Updated HTMl

```
<div class="container">    
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="panel panel-success">
<div class="panel-heading"><a href="Varieties 
Grains/amaranth_hopireddye.html">Hopi Red Dye</a></div>
<div class="panel-body"><a href="Varieties 
Grains/amaranth_hopireddye.html"><img 
src="Images/amaranth_hopireddye.jpg" class="img-responsive" 
style="width:100%" alt="Image"></a></div>
<div class="panel-footer">500 seeds per packet<br>$4.00 per 
Packet</div>
<div class="panel-footer"><div align="center"><input type="number" 
id="orderQty001" value="1" style="width: 50px; margin-right: 10px;"><a 
href="#" class="productItem btn btn-primary center-block" data-
name="Hopi Red Dye " data-s="500 seeds" data-price="400" data-
id="001">Add to Cart</a></div></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="panel panel-success">
<div class="panel-heading"><a href="Varieties 
Grains/amaranth_dedosdedios.html">Dedos de Dios</a></div>
<div class="panel-body"><a href="Varieties 
Grains/amaranth_dedosdedios.html"><img 
src="Images/amaranth_dedosdedios.jpg" class="img-responsive" 
style="width:100%" alt="Image"></a></div>
<div class="panel-footer">500 seeds per packet<br>$4.00 per 
Packet</div>
<div class="panel-footer"><div align="center"><input type="number" 
id="orderQty002" value="1" style="width: 50px; margin-right: 10px;"><a 
href="#" class="productItem btn btn-primary center-block" data-
name="Dedos de Dios " data-s="500 seeds" data-price="400" data-
id="002">Add to Cart</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Updated Javascript:

```
var shopcart = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
outputCart();
$(".productItem").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var iteminfo = $(this.dataset)[0];
var inputId = "orderQty" + this.attr('data-id');
iteminfo.qty = document.getElementById(inputId).value;

var itemincart = false;
$.each(shopcart, function (index, value) {
//console.log(index + '  ' + value.id);
if (value.id == iteminfo.id) {
value.qty = parseInt(value.qty) + parseInt(iteminfo.qty);
itemincart = true;
}
})
if (!itemincart) {
shopcart.push(iteminfo);
}
sessionStorage["sca"] = JSON.stringify(shopcart);
outputCart();

})
```

I've also tried to assign a class and unique id to each  element, but then I can't figure out how to get the unique user input in my javascript.

Comment: `orderQty_001` was an example I gave, but there's no need for the underscore so I removed it when updating my answer. You need to remove the underscore from your ids.

Also it should be `document.getElementById(inputId)` not `document.getElementById("inputId")`.

Comment: I've removed the underscore and updated my javascript.  My "add to cart" button is still not getting iteminfo.qty.

Comment: Can you try logging `iteminfo` before pushing it onto `shopcart` and see what it looks like?

Comment: Oh... `$(".productItem")` should be `$("#productItem")`, try that.

Comment: Add to Cart button is still not working.

Comment: When I had the Id of "orderQty" for every <input> element (which I know they should be unique), and used iteminfo.qty = document.getElementByID("orderQty").value in my script my "Add to Cart" button was sending prices and quantities to the shopping cart.  However, it was only using the input value "Id" of the first product since the Id's were all the same and that was the first one listed.  Is there no way to get my script to distinguish the difference between each product's <input> value? Or would I have to write an if else portion of the function for each unique Id?  Just throwing out ideas.

Comment: I finally got smart and started running the code to debug it. Updating my answer once again now.

Comment: I tried the 1/31 updates, but still couldn't get it to execute.  I didn't know about jsfiddle before.  I just put the whole page into jsfiddle.  I reverted the html and js to what I had originally.  Maybe this can give you a better idea of what's going on in the code and what I'm doing wrong.  Again, thank you for all of your help.  https://jsfiddle.net/gdub731/vuds2h9y/8/

Comment: Updated my answer. There wasn't much I did besides adding my code in and ripping the javascript out to its designated box on jsfiddle, so I'm not certain what problems you were running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `id`s unique.

One way to do this is to append the `data-id`s to each `input` id. For example `id="orderQty001"`. Then in the JavaScript you can find the corresponding input based on the clicked element's `data-id`:

```
var inputId = "orderQty" + this.attr('data-id'); // 'this' is the clicked <a> element
iteminfo.qty = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
```

And the rest of the JavaScript could stay the same I think.

Edit (1/31): Since there are still problems I started a jsFiddle to run the code. Firstly, I found that `this` in the click handler is not a jQuery object, but a DOM element. As such, `attr` is not a function, and instead we must use `getAttribute` as follows:

```
var inputId = "orderQty" + this.getAttribute('data-id');
```

Next, I noticed a bug where the `qty` of the cart item was not getting set correctly. I found that the problem code was `iteminfo.qty = document.getElementById(inputId).value;`. This statement is a problem because it is manipulating the DOM earlier than we'd like. That is, it is setting the `qty` on the element immediately, instead of after we calculate the new `qty`. So instead we should declare a temporary variable to hold the `input`'s `value`:

```
var qtyToAdd = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
```

Additionally, we must now set the `iteminfo.qty` before we add it to the cart for the first time:

```
if (!itemincart) {
    iteminfo.qty = parseInt(qtyToAdd);
    shopcart.push(iteminfo);
}
```

Here is the fiddle with these changes in place: https://jsfiddle.net/7vwyh03h/. The HTML was unchanged aside from formatting.

Edit (2/5): I've integrated my changes into your fiddle. All my previous updates edits are included. Updated fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/aougb72r/. When you click 'Add to Cart' the cart gets updated as you can see in the console and by checking the cart.

I changed one more thing, which was making `iteminfo` a clone of the `dataset` with:

```
var iteminfo = Object.assign({}, $(this.dataset)[0]);
```

This will make sure we don't edit the DOM accidentally when we really only want to manipulate the shopping cart in that function.

Check it out and see if you're still seeing any problems.

Comment: How do I add the user input value to the data set in the html?

Comment: Didn't mean to hit enter so soon.  Thank you for the tips.  I tried to replace iteminfo.qty = document.getElementByID("orderQty").value; with iteminfo.qty = this.value; and iteminfo.id = this.attr('data-id');.  After doing this, my "Add to Cart" buttons do not do anything.

Comment: Oh sorry actually I'm wrong because `$(".productItem")` gets the `a` tag, not the `input`. But I would recommend making the input ids unique and relate to the `data-id`. Changing them so something like `orderQty_001`. Updating answer now.

Comment: I just tried updating my code with your new suggestions and it's still not working.  When I click "add to cart" nothing happens.  I'll post an updated chunk of html and my updated javascript.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The changes you made to the fiddle worked perfectly!  Thank you so much for all of the help.